# Запус программы из bat-файла с админскими правами

Tags: bat

Как запустить программу через bat-файл так, чтобы программа открылась с правами админа?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

использовать [runas](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771525(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: Имя пользователя не известно

Comment: администратор он и в Африке администратор, нет?

Comment: Нет например у меня на компе админ это Никита

Comment: Ну так может можно как нибудь этосделать подругому

Comment: В 7 винде запретили администратора по умолчанию. И предлагают создавать mui файл.
вот [пишут](http://www.howtogeek.com/124087/how-to-create-a-shortcut-that-lets-a-standard-user-run-an-application-as-administrator/) как это разрулить стандартными способами.

[Здесь](http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/) человек пишет, что он создал утилиту, которая решает эти вопросы, но я не тестил ее.

Comment: Это не подходит

Comment: В Африке нет Никит?)))

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, неа :(  
 
http://www.andein.ru/mir/africanskie.html